# Searching model number of Shimano shifting lever

Tags: maintenance, shimano, shifter, shifting

On my daughters bike, the cover of the revo shifting lever is broken. The specifications of the bike say the shifting lever is SL-RS35, but when I look at images in the net, these look completely different. I uploaded images of the levers to https://i.stack.imgur.com/xznaV.jpg Maybe someone knows which model this could be?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a Shimano SL-RS41-7 is compatible. I have one in my spare parts box and they look identical. A quick google search shows lots of sources. Most E Bay listings are under $20 for the set.

Answer (score 4):

SL-RS35 is correct, there are newer versions however, there are many you can replace it with. Shimano uses a 2 to 1 pull ratio for shifters, Sram uses a 1 to 1 except for their entry level MX lines.

In layman's terms you will be fine with just about any twist shifter made for 3x7 speed, Shimano Tourney or Revo twist, Sunrace, or Sram MRX Comp

Compatibility should not be an issue with these entry level parts. There are also several on Amazon but I personally like to support my local bike shop.

http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AShimano%20Revoshift

Here are some compatible Sram MRX shifter for sale online
http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Drehgriff-Set-SRAM-MRX-Grip-Shift-7-3-fach-/181693382982?hash=item2a4dc50146:g:DMMAAOSwGiRTqtpz

Located in Germany :)

Comment: Nope! totally missed that lol thanks, yes it would be extremely excessive, however those parts are also readily available in Germany.

Comment: I Got it, was already on it. Provided a link being sold out of Germany